# github action yaml: how to refer an item in a matrix array?

Tags: python-3.x, github-actions

That's my matrix:

```yaml
jobs:
   check-test:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      strategy:
         matrix:
            python-version: ["3.6", "3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]
```

And I have this current conditional (that's working):

```yaml
          if: matrix.python-version == 3.6
```

How can I replace `3.6` by the first item of my matrix? I mean, how to tell in `yaml`:

```yaml
if: matrix.python-version == "the_first_item_from_matrix.python-version"
```

And no, `matrix.python-version[0]` (or `[1]`, I don't know how it's indexed) won't work.

The reasoning here is: in some point I will drop `3.6` support and I don't want to remember to remove any `3.6` hardcoded in my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a simple workaround using the `strategy.job-index` property. According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#strategy-context), this property is defined as follows:

> The index of the current job in the matrix. Note: This number is a zero-based number. The first job's index in the matrix is 0.

You can use this property to ensure that a step is only executed for the first job in the matrix.

Here is a minimal workflow to demonstrate the idea:

```yaml
name: demo
on:
  push:
jobs:
  demo:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: ['3.7', '3.10']
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - if: strategy.job-index == 0
        run: echo '3.7' && exit 1

      - if: strategy.job-index == 1
        run: echo '3.10' && exit 1
```

Here are screenshots to show the result:

[image]

[image]

Sadly this workaround will get more complicated once we start to work with a matrix that has more than one dimension.